# Insert data into an istream

Tags: c++, matrix, operator-overloading, ifstream, istream

I'm reading data from an `ifstream`. I have an object whose `operator>>` reads an integer n, an integer m and then n rows of m integers (a matrix).

In my `ifstream`, I have a matrix list but without the integers n and m at the start of each matrix block. I would nevertheless like to read the `istream` using the `>>` operator of my object.

I don't want to change my `operator>>`. In addition, I would not add the number of rows and columns before each matrices in my file because they are constant.

So is there a way to insert these two integers of fixed value into my `ifstream` to be able to use the existing operator `>>` of the matrix?

*data file with matrices of 3 rows and 4 columns:*

```
0 1 2 5
1 4 8 6
1 4 7 3

4 5 6 8 
6 9 7 2
8 7 9 4

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The challenge is that once your matrix starts to extract something, you have no control anymore on the `istream` that is used.

You can think of the following alternatives:

1. Creating an adapter for the matrix with its own `operator<<` overload.  You can then tailor the behavior of the extractor.  But you'd probably have to rewrite the full extractor. It fits the requirement, is uggly, but simple and effective.
2. Same as 1, but trick your adapter's overload, to use an intermediary `stringstream`.  You woud then output to the `stringstream` the predetermined m and n, then you would read n x m elements from the `istream` to output them to the `stringstream` and then use the normal matrix `operator>>` on the `stringstream`.  But all this is very complex, not performant if you have huge matrixes, and requires to think twice about everything that could go wrong.  Do this only if your matrix elements are difficult to parse (e.g. symbolic CAS expressions). Otherwise go to 1 ;-)
3. A better approach seems to expose in your matrix a new member `istream& read(&istream, size_t m, size_t n)`,  refactor its `operator>>` to extract m and n and then forward to `read()`.  You can then create an adapter, with an `operator>>` overload that would directly invoke `read()` with the predetermined m and n. Lean, clean, elegant.

Personally, I'd opt for 3.

Comment: Thanks I'll opt for the third one seems to be the easier thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

No.

An istream is an input stream. It's a one-way flow of data. You can't put data in it the other way.

Updating/changing your `operator>>` is the correct thing to do.

Comment: I disagree with that because I want to keep my matrix operator >> generic.

Comment: @Sevla I'm sorry to hear that.

Comment: Maybe we could provide some other structural ideas but we have no idea what your code looks like, so we can't. Trying to hack the input stream is definitely wrong, though.

Comment: I want to keep my current data structure.

Comment: Is there a way perhaps to build another istream resulting from another one ?

Comment: Well, you _could_ read the whole file then construct a new `istringstream` from it and use that instead. But it's not a very elegant solution. It would be better to make your `operator>>` not have to be "one or the other", but to support both approaches, and when the dimensions _are_ available read them into some member variable for use by the `operator>>`. When they're not, provide that information statically instead.

Comment: OK I'll just create another member function where I'll give the number of rows and columns in parameters then.